# relative adverb - when and in which

Tags: relative-adverbs

> Mary Decker surprised the sports world in the 1970s **when** she reported that she ate a plate of spaghetti noodles the night before a race.

In the above sentence, is **"when"** a relative adverb? Can "when" be changed to "in which"?

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: What are "spaghetti noodles"? Are they anything like spaghetti?

Comment: Yes, I think "spaghetti noodles" means just spaghetti. I extracted the sentence from an exam passage.

Comment: Traditional grammar calls it an adverb, but some modern grammars call it a preposition.